# Unable to install iOS app locally on phone after moving to distribution stage

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have recently switched my app from the development to the distribution stage, but now I'm unable to install the app from Xcode to my test phone directly. The simulators work but I need to test this on an actual device, and testflight just takes too long for what I want to test.

When attempting to install the app to my phone via Xcode, I get this error

```
Failed to code sign <App Name>.
None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices: <device name>
```

However, this device is set up on my developer account with the correct UDID and everything.

I'm wondering if its still possible to install my app directly from Xcode onto my device, and how to do so if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "switched", what did you actually change?

Comment: @PhillipMills The signing certificate to my application

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your Provisioning profile configuration on Xcode?

Comment: @Darklex pardon my inexperience but where would I find that?

Comment: Click in name project, choose app under TARGETS, be sure to specify the Team in Identity first section, after the look into Build Settings and in the Code signing section be sure to specify in Automatic or try setting all values to iOS Developer.

Comment: Is none of that is familiar to you, try to look in Warnings or directly in Identity   and try to click the warning button to resolve everything.

Comment: @Darklex I ended up just having to set my code signing identity back to automatic iOS developer. If my app is in distribution, would this binary be acceptable in the app store?

Comment: You are still developing even when you install the app on your device using Xcode. When you are ready to submit to the App Store you need to use the "archive" command in Xcode to generate a binary for submission.

Comment: @Paulw11 so I can just leave the code signing identity alone then?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to change it. You would only change it if you had multiple developer accounts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Darklex, it turned out that under the build settings in my target application, I had somehow managed to change the code signing identity to iOS Distribution when I needed it as iOS Development.